# Change ZF2 ExceptionStrategy from Controller

Tags: zend-framework2

Are there any methods to change ExceptionStrategy from the Controller within Zend Framework 2?
I need this for some actions which return JsonModel. But when Exception occurs standard ExceptionStrategy doesn't put excpetion info into JsonModel (the same promblem: [ExceptionStrategy doesn't work with JsonStrategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625360/exceptionstrategy-doesnt-work-with-jsonstrategy)).

I've tried this with no result:

```
$exceptionStrategy = new JsonExceptionStrategy();
$exceptionStrategy->attach($this->getEventManager());
```

JsonExceptionStrategy - from link above.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this inside the controller on not on the onBoostrap method of the Module.php. If you only wanted to do it for certain actions you could only attache the event based on the uri.

Comment: Yes, I want to do it only in certain actions and I don't know how to determine when to use JsonException. When request have "Accept: application/json" I use event manager and send respone with JsonModel. But while uploading file (in ExtJS form) there is no possibility to change request headers. Is it right way to "hardcode" controller/action in bootstrap? (Though I can write rules in config and just use this config in Bootstrap)

Comment: You could consider doing the check in a controller plugin that seems the most appropriate place. Then when the the Content-Type is application/json you can change the exception strategy.

Comment: Could you please show an example?